# grep sequence of chars and numbers (grep only)

Tags: regex, grep

So I have this problem where I need to use the grep command.
So I got 52 cards of 13 ranks and 4 colors.

The ranks consist of A,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,T(for ten),J,Q and K(king). The four colors: c,d,h,s.

Now I've got file (cards.txt) with all possible combinations of 13 cards.
Example: 8cKc6s4dKd8sQc4c2s6h9dTc4h

Now the question is output all combinations that contains 4 cards of the same ranks.

β = { h ∈ H | h contains 4 cards of the same ranks}.
examples:

Kd9dJs5sKs7c5c6cKcJhKhTh7h ∈ β

AdTdTc2d2cTsKh6c3c6s6dKc4h ∉ β

(Problem is I know how to use grep command for sequence of characters but only when they're next to each other. Help plz)

Comment: `echo Kd9dJs5sKs7c5c6cKcJhKhTh7h | grep '[^K]*K[^K]*K[^K]*K[^K]*K[^K]*'`?

Comment: no that's not why what I'm looking for. I'm looking for all combinations with the similar pattern as in the example you gave. But the grep command might be a good beginning I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you want *back-references* (see [this link](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_06)):

```
grep '\([A23456789TJQK]\).*\1.*\1.*\1' cards.txt
```

If grep matches a character from `A23456789TJQK`, then, because of the parentheses `\(...\)`, grep will refer to it as `\1` (this is the back-reference).

The pattern can also be written as follows:

```
grep '\([A23456789TJQK]\)\(.*\1\)\{3\}' cards.txt
```

Comment: Thanks! That's what I've been looking for. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Thx, it's been on my mind since ages but you pulled it off again.

Answer (score 0):

```
while read line
do
  if echo $line | sed 's/\(.\)./\1\n/g' | sort | uniq -c | grep -q '^ *4'
  then
    echo $line
  fi
done < cards.txt
```

Comment: This might be the right answer but i can't use scripts. I can only use the grep command in the terminal.

Comment: You don't need to put this in a script, just type it at the bash prompt. If not then be more specific as to what commands are allowed in the terminal (it's hard to believe that sort, uniq are disabled?).

Comment: Actually it's an exercise where I can only use grep command. The previous the question of the exercise for example, consisted of listing all combinations containing no cards with pictures(eg. K,J,Q) so the command was : grep [KJQ] -v cards.txt. Now for this question I have to do the same.(mainly using grep)

Comment: No, this is a exercise given to us by the professor. https://github.ugent.be/Computergebruik/CG-practica-2015-2016/blob/master/regular-expressions/kaarten-1/opgave.md